# AJAX Doesn't Load the the second nested PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

My AJAX call gets triggered for one condition, however when it proceeds to  new nested php function it showing the output is the php processing file...Below is my Code.. i am using bootstrap 3.0 framework on this one and pure javascript.

```
<!-- Modal Register -->
<div id="register" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-md-offset-1" style="max-width:400px;">

     <form role="form" method="POST"  id="reg" action="reg-check.php">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary" style="border:1px solid black;">
                        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:black;">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                Register
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white;">&times;</button>
                            </h3>

                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body ">
                                <div class="login-box">

                                    <img src="images/newlogo2.png"  width="100%;"><br/><br/>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name"  autofocus />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email" required/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="password"  id="pass" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="password" id = "pass1"class="form-control" name="password1" placeholder="Confirm Password" required />
                                        </div>
                                            <label>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree">&nbsp;I agree to the terms and conditions of the website and cookie policy</label>                              
                                </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
                                    <p><span id="errorMessage"></span></p>
                                    <button  id="submitreg" type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success" data-dismiss="none" onClick="javascript:ajax_post();">
                                        <span class="btn-label">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                        </span>Submit</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger" >
                                        <span class="btn-label">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                                        </span>lReset</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </form>
             <div><p id="errorMessage"></p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

My Ajax Scripts`

```
    function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "reg-check.php?";
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
   var return_data = hr.responseText;
   console.log(return_data);
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = return_data;
   }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

MY PHP Script

```
<?php
require ("/Pages/dbc.php");

if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['mobile']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password1']))
{
    $name =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $mobile =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile']);
    $email =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password1 =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password1']);

$query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `mobile`= $mobile");
$numrows =mysql_num_rows($query);   

    if($numrows == 0){
        $query1 =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `email`= '$email'");
        $numrows1 =mysql_num_rows($query1); 
        if($numrows1==0){
            if($password == $password1){
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cabs4rent`.`register` (`name`, `mobile`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$mobile', '$email', '$password');");
                    echo "Registration Successful";
            }else{
                echo "Passwords do not match";
            }

        }else{

            echo "Emails is already registered";
        }

    }else{

        echo "Mobile Number Already Registered";
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Please fill all the details';
}
exit;
```

?>

---

I will changing to mysqli/pdo very soon.

The problem was with the action attr in my form element. hence i removed the form element and and in ajax made changes and used urlencoder to send the data... everything work smoothly..

Here is the code

```
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    //preventDefault();
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var name =document.getElementById("name").value;
    var mobile =document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    var email =document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password =document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var password1 =document.getElementById("pass1").value;
    var vars = "name="+name+"&mobile="+mobile+"&email="+email+"&password="+password+"&password1="+password1;
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "reg-check.php?";
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
   var return_data = hr.responseText;
   console.log(return_data);
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = return_data;
   }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request

    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

Form without the formelement

```
<!-- Modal Register -->
    <div id="register" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-md-offset-1" style="max-width:400px;">


                        <div class="panel panel-primary" style="border:1px solid black;">
                            <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:black;">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">
                                    Register
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white;">&times;</button>
                                </h3>

                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body ">
                                    <div class="login-box">

                                        <img src="images/newlogo2.png"  width="100%;"><br/><br/>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                                </span>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control"id="name"  name="name" placeholder="Name"  autofocus />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
                                                </span>
                                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="mobile"  name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>
                                                </span>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control"  id="email"  name="email" placeholder="email" required/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>
                                                </span>
                                                <input type="password"  id="pass" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>
                                                </span>
                                                <input type="password" id = "pass1"class="form-control" name="password1" placeholder="Confirm Password" required />
                                            </div>

                                    </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
                                        <p><span id="errorMessage"></span></p>
                                        <button  id="submitreg" type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success" data-dismiss="none" onClick="javascript:ajax_post();">
                                            <span class="btn-label">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                            </span>Submit</button>
                                        <button type="button" id="regReset" onclick="rested();"     class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger" >
                                            <span class="btn-label">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                                            </span>Reset</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <p><span id="errorMessage"></span></p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

No changes made to to PHP script.

Comment: First of all get rid of `mysql` and use [mysqli](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). mysql is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not posting any data.

```
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
var url = "reg-check.php?";
```

doesn't add any of the values to the url.

You schould do something like

```
var name_value=document.getElementById('name').value;
var mobile_value=document.getElementById('mobile').value;
var url = "reg-check.php?" + "name=" + name_value + "&mobile=" + mobile_val;
```